# MTU сетевого интерфейса в Linux (язык C)

Tags: linux, c, ethernet

Как установить MTU сетевого интерфейса в Linux на языке C?

Comment: Догадался: ifreq opts; opts.ifr_ifru.ifru_mtu = 1500;
        if(ioctl(m_inSocket, SIOCSIFFLAGS, &opts) < 0) {
            throw SocketException(errno);
    } Правильно?

Comment: `trow` - оператор C++, не C

Comment: Понятно-же что не средствами языка, а Linux написан на C и вызавать C из C++ не трудно!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Советую взять за основу исходники iproute2, файл iplink.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <linux/sockios.h>
#include <linux/if.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

static int get_ctl_fd(void)
{
        int s_errno;
        int fd;

        fd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
        if (fd >= 0)
                return fd;
        s_errno = errno;
        fd = socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
        if (fd >= 0)
                return fd;
        fd = socket(PF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
        if (fd >= 0)
                return fd;
        errno = s_errno;
        perror("Cannot create control socket");
        return -1;
}

static int set_mtu(const char *dev, int mtu)
{
        struct ifreq ifr;
        int s;

        s = get_ctl_fd();
        if (s < 0)
                return -1;

        memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));
        strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, dev, IFNAMSIZ);
        ifr.ifr_mtu = mtu;
        if (ioctl(s, SIOCSIFMTU, &ifr) < 0) {
                perror("SIOCSIFMTU");
                close(s);
                return -1;
        }
        close(s);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Да сильно походит на правду, провери пока не могу. Спасибо!

Comment: @cipher_web, у меня работает

Comment: Ну значит работает...

Comment: доп коммент -- вопрос: в каких единицах задается MTU, при задании int 1500 падает интерфейс наглухо (в т.ч. браузер)

Comment: @cipher_web, MTU задаётся в байтах, это размер пакета на канальном уровне, тот который ниже IP. 1500 - стандартный размер для эзернет. Если MTU вернуть к предыдущему значению интерфейс не оживает?